# SBackup when turning my PC off

Tags: backup, shutdown, services

I have installed and configured *sbackup* as explained in this [Ubuntu Community Guide to SBackup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite). It is very convenient for me to launch the backup process the first time I shut down my PC each day. The idea would be that when I tell Ubuntu to shut my system down it launches the backup process if that is the first time in the day that my PC is halted. This way it doesn't mess with my workflow, just take a little more to shut down (no problem since I could then go away and let it finish by itself).

Some instructions are given in the [aforementioned guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite) but unfortunately [it doesn't seem to work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1382252) and even the given link to download the `sbackupd` file is broken.

Any help with this?

Comment: Hm. R. Taylor mentioned 9 months later, that my answer contained a question, which I shall ask in a comment. `Can you start sbackup from the shell/with a command?` - Since you didn't answer it in May last year, I expect you not to answer it today.

Answer (score 1):

The normal shutdown only waits a very short time, before forcing running programs to quit.

I guess you need another approach: Start a command, which first issues the backup, and then init the shutdown.

Comment: The question in this answer is really a comment, not an answer. I'll edit it out, and you can post a comment asking for the info you need.